# Eclipse PTP Parallel Debugging

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, debug, parallel-processing

I have a problem with Eclipse PTP 201906. I would like to perform debug in parallel with 4 cores using Eclipse. I adjust the debug configuration with

- Local connection
- Arguments: -np 4

and begin debugging. I see "Operation in progress" in "Progress Information Box" but progress stucks around ~20%. Could somebody help me on this issue? By the way, when I use the older versions:

- PTP 201903: Can not use local connection due to error in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904208/launch-error-provider-com-sun-xml-not-found-in-eclipse-ptp/56603267#56603267 . Therefore, I use the PTP 201906
- PTP 201809 and older (e.g. Neon.3): Problem related Java

My

- OS:               Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Eclipse Platform: PTP 201906
- Java versions:    11 (default) / 8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to https://www.eclipse.org/lists/ptp-user/msg03410.html , removing `.eclipsesettings` may get rid of the issue.
That did not work for me.

Comment: Related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939540/ptp-fails-to-connect-to-debugger